# How to avoid extra pages before titlepage with scrbook and glossaries? Strange problem

Tags: koma-script, glossaries, scrbook

I am encountering a very strange problem when combining the `scrbook` class and `glossaries` package. When using the `glossaries` package, two extra pages will always be added before the titelpage. This is obviously unwanted behaviour. Here is an example (cropped picture):

[image: Example of output]

If I do not load the `glossaries` package, I only get the lower two pages. This no option of coruse, because I do want to use the package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{glossaries} % Toggle this on off to see the effect.

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    This is a titlepage
\end{titlepage} 

The next page.
\end{document}
```

Log file as per request:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX) (format=pdflatex 2012.10.19)  19 OCT 2012 10:40
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**TN-Tradeoff-New.tex
(./TN-Tradeoff-New.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (book)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
Package: scrkbase 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent 
basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
Package: scrbase 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
 basics and keyval usage)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package: scrlfile 2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
Package: tocbasic 2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 117.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 118.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 119.
Class scrbook Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrbook)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 1368
.

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize11pt.clo
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (11p
t)
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package: typearea 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip41
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip42
\ta@vblk=\skip43
\ta@temp=\skip44
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 47.2316pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = -12.5192pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.60002pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1213.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip45
\belowcaptionskip=\skip46
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box26
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2012/09/21 v3.03 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16
\XKV@depth=\count89
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
))
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2012/05/21 v1.06 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count90
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count91
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks17
\@glsmrest=\toks18
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0
\@emptytoks=\toks19
\ex@=\dimen103
)
\gls@level=\count92
\@gls@tmpb=\toks20
\gls@tmplen=\skip47
\glswrite=\write3
\glskeylisttok=\toks21
\glslabeltok=\toks22
\glsshorttok=\toks23
\glslongtok=\toks24

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2007/07/04 v1.01 (NLCT)
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2012/09/21 v3.03 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip48
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2012/09/21 v3.03 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2004/02/01 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip49
\LTright=\skip50
\LTpre=\skip51
\LTpost=\skip52
\LTchunksize=\count93
\LTcapwidth=\dimen104
\LT@head=\box27
\LT@firsthead=\box28
\LT@foot=\box29
\LT@lastfoot=\box30
\LT@cols=\count94
\LT@rows=\count95
\c@LT@tables=\count96
\c@LT@chunks=\count97
\LT@p@ftn=\toks25
)
Class scrbook Info: longtable captions redefined on input line 43.
\glsdescwidth=\skip53
\glspagelistwidth=\skip54
)
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2012/09/21 v3.03 (NLCT)

(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count98
\ST@wd=\dimen105
\ST@rightskip=\skip55
\ST@leftskip=\skip56
\ST@parfillskip=\skip57
\ST@pageleft=\dimen106
\ST@headht=\dimen107
\ST@tailht=\dimen108
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen109
\ST@pboxht=\dimen110
\ST@lineht=\dimen111
\ST@stretchht=\dimen112
\ST@prevht=\dimen113
\ST@toadd=\dimen114
\ST@dimen=\dimen115
\ST@pbox=\box31
))
(c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2012/09/21 v3.03 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip58
))
(./TN-Tradeoff-New.aux)
\openout1 = `TN-Tradeoff-New.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
 [1

{c:/texlive/2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2


] [3]

Package glossaries Warning: \makeglossaries hasn't been used,
the glossaries will not be updated.


Package glossaries Warning: No \printglossary or \printglossaries found.
This document will not have a glossary.

[4] (./TN-Tradeoff-New.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3539 strings out of 493488
 53020 string characters out of 3144747
 149240 words of memory out of 3000000
 6852 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4293 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,7n,39p,1466b,170s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<c:/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/ams
fonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on TN-Tradeoff-New.pdf (4 pages, 13734 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 21 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 13 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with `scrbook.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b` and `glossaries.sty    2012/09/21 v3.03`.

Comment: I am using the latest packages of TeXLive (updated today). I am compiling with `lualatex`, might that be a problem? (Edit: just checked, is not a problem.)

Comment: I just tried with a current TeXLive 2012 and had no problems too. Did you delete the auxiliary files?

Comment: Yes, it even happens after deleting all auxiliary files. I'm a bit desperate about this strange issue right now. PS: It started happening in `scrartcl` right now, too.

Comment: Show your log-file so that I can compare it with mine.

Comment: I gladly provided my log file in the question now.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. The log-files are quite identical. I can force additional pages before the titlepage by inserting invisible utf8-chars but this doesn't depend on glossaries. Nevertheless I suggest that you inspect your file for such chars.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. I used Notepad++ to display all symbols but there are no invisible characters.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}` to your example and compile. Does it give an error?

Comment: Believe it or not, same problem. I will try compiling this at home on my Unix machine.

Comment: I didn't ask if it gives the same problem but if it gives an error (this would indicate some non-ascii-char somewhere).

Comment: @Ingo Have you any news about the problem?

Comment: Not really. The problem still prevails on my work PC with Windows 7. On my Unix system at home I do not have the problem. We might want to keep the question open just in case somebody else has the same problem.

Comment: @Ingo The problem might be in a Byte Order Mark (BOM) at the beginning of your file. What editor are you using on Windows?

Comment: I used TeXMaker. Luckily however, my employer now made it possible for me to use Linux at my work place. And as such I will unfortunately not be able to reproduce the problem anymore.